# Icon of Gnome Pomodoro does not show up. How do I fix it?

Tags: gnome, icons, system-tray

I've been using GNOME Pomodoro already in Ubuntu 21.04 and it worked just fine (installed with `sudo apt install gnome-shell-pomodoro`). However, I had to reinstall Ubuntu for some unrelated reason and now Pomodoro sort of works, but not properly.

The Pomodoro Window opens and it does it's basic job, but the app icon in the top right corner is missing. Thus I don't see if it is running (usually I'd run it with the window closed). I am also not able to use the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>somekey</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to pause/start it).

I have already purged and reinstalled it, restarted the laptop, but still doesn't work

How do I fix this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you also enable it through the ```gnome-shell-extensions``` application, or ```gnome-tweaks```?

Comment: Thank you!! That did the trick :-)
This is what worked in the end:
1) sudo apt install gnome-shell-pomodoro
2) Tweaks > Extenstions > Pomodoro > activate

Comment: Tweaks doesn't works in 22.04 ;-( No Extension panel.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work on 22.04 https://haydenjames.io/ubuntu-22-04-install-gnome-extensions-manager-workaround/

Answer (score 1):

> This is what worked in the end:
>
> 1. `sudo apt install gnome-shell-pomodoro`
> 2. Tweaks → *Extenstions* → *Pomodoro* → activate.

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345223/icon-of-gnome-pomodoro-does-not-show-up-how-do-i-fix-it/1494003#comment2298550_1345223).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was opening GNOME Extensions → *Pomodoro* → enable it.